# Choosing constants for probabilistic bounds

Tags: probability, bounds

I am studying probabilistic bounds and I have a question regarding how to choose constants from complexity classes.

Specifically, consider a biased coin which has the probability of one side $p = \frac{1}{2} - \epsilon$. In order to be $\delta$-confident (i.e. correct with probability $\geq 1-\delta$) about which side is the less probable one, the following number of tosses ("queries") are needed [1]:

$$q = \Theta \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \cdot \log \frac{1}{\delta} \right)$$

I understand that, for proof of correctness, it's sufficient to express $q$ using complexity classes (because we are interested in lower / upper bounds), but how do you concretely approach this when implementing the algorithm in a programming language, that is, what is a concrete value of $q$ in this case?

Thank you.

[1] Mousavi, Nima. "How tight is Chernoff bound." (2010).

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "choose constants" and "concrete value of" in this question?  Those usages don't appear consistent with the meaning of $\Theta.$

Comment: In literature you often find these kind of statements: "Sample $q = \Theta \left( \log(1/\delta) / \epsilon^2 \right)$ times from distribution $\mathbf{p}$". When implementing such algorithms you need to give an actual value to $q$. I am asking how to choose such a value given that you only know that $q = \Theta(...)$.

Comment: I suppose an actual lower bound for $q$ must be derived manually (see [2.4. here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~ecprice/courses/randomized/notes/lec2.pdf)).

Comment: That's right, because $\Theta$ tells you nothing about bounds or the actual rate at which the asymptotic value is approached. By itself it has no practical value--it's only a theoretical guide for choosing scalable algorithms.  But in conjunction with small amounts of experimental data it's an extraordinarily useful result.